# XCeed PropertyGrid: How to set the right title?

Tags: wpf, xceed

I've implemented ICustomTypeDescriptor to provide my custom descriptor to the XCeed Propertygrid.

```
public class MyDescriptor : ICustomTypeDescriptor, IDisposable
{
    public MyDescriptor(IMyInterface metadata)
    {
         /* Use object metadata to build the type descriptor */
    }
}
```

This works fine, except that the PropertyGrid has as Title "MyDescriptor". I've tried implementing GetAttributes()

```
public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
{
    string theRightTitle = metaData.GetTitle(); // Dynamic title, differs depending on metaData object provided in constructor.
    Attribute[] attributes = new Attribute[] {new DescriptionAttribute(theRightTitle) };
    return new AttributeCollection(attributes);
}
```

But that doesn't work... How do I ensure that the title of my grid is correct?

**Edit**: So what I need is a *dynamic* way of generating the Title for the PropertyGrid. I've updated the code samples above to reflect this.

Comment: Does it use the class name in the header? In this case you can override [GetClassName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.getclassname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), I suppose.

Comment: Overriding GetClassName does not result in the returned class name being shown in the propertygrid. It still shows "MyDescriptor"

Comment: I don't have XCeed, so I'm just guessing here: it can be [DisplayName attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `ToString` method override or [GetComponentName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.getcomponentname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: As I remember, I tried all except the ToString, thanks for the suggestion, will check if that is it. Edit: Neither ToString or GetComponentName achieves the desired result. I've returned DisplayNameAttribute via GetAttributes(), this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see at the top of the PropertyGrid is not the Title, it’s the TypeName along with an empty title. If you want to see a title beside the TypeName, make sure your class contains a “Name” property. Without the “Name” property, an empty string is added as the title.

```
public class MyDescriptor : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public string Name
    {
      get
      {
        return "AAA";
      }
    }
    . . .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have decorated my class with DisplayName attribute and works right.

```
[DisplayName("My Custom Title")]
public class MyConfiguration
{ ... }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, this is not what I need. The title should be dynamically settable for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use combination of static and dynamic info like:-

```
[DisplayName("Data")]
public class MyDescriptor : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    public string Name
    {
      get
      {
        return " - My Title";
      }
    }
    . . .
}
```

Title of property grid will be "Data - My Title"